# Typescript: Can a type be parameterized on its own keys?

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a type where the values are references to its own properties. Something along the lines of:

```
type T = {[k:string]: keyof *a reference to this type*}; //
```

so that you could write something like this:

```
const t:T = {
  a:"b", // valid
  b:"a", // valid
  c:"d" // invalid since "d" is not a property of t
};
```

Is this possible without breaking the type up or explicitly specifying the properties up front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No *concrete* type `T` has such a definition, but you can represent your `T` as a [generic constraint](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints).  That means instead of annotating like `const t: T = ...`, you'd want to use a generic helper function and call it like `const t = asT(...)`.  Like this:

```
const asT = <T extends Record<keyof T, keyof T>>(t: T) => t;

const t = asT({
  a: "b",
  b: "a",
  c: "d" // error! // "d" not assignable to "a"|"b"|"c"
});
```

This gives you the error exactly where you expect it.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhhAKjAvDAPMgpgDylsAEwhgCUtQAnQ9AaywE8QAzGRAGhnqdcQD4+ACigAuNgEpUfGFADcAKHmhIsWGgSJBAb3kx4YgEQAjA+10wjhuKfPBDhAzAD0TmFkqUQlAITPXBhxgwEFgECABLAHMwOCMAGywZEBgDawAfYwMM4AN5AF9xWRggA)